# How to give the progress value morethan hundred to progressview

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that iam using the progress view.In this i need to give the progress value more than hundred.If i give more than hundred then that fill the total bar.So please tell me how to do this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`-setProgress:animated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIProgressView/setProgress%3aanimated%3a), send it `1.0` if your progress value is (for whatever reason) greater than or equal to `1.0`, where `1.0` is your true maximum value. If your raw maximum is `100`, map it to `1.0`, so that values below `100` indicate a percentage of completion, and values of `100` and above are full completion.

Comment: But i need to give 13.6 to progress.When i send this value.This fill the total bar.But i dont need that one.

Comment: Divide 13.6 by 100. This gives you 0.136, which is between the progress indicator's range of 0 and 1. Read the documentation for `UIProgressView`, which I linked to in my answer.

Comment: How to increase that max value

Comment: Yes, but with some basic math, you can map your own minimum and maximum to a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: You don't increase the maximum value. You map your own progress value to a value between 0 and 1, if necessary, and use that mapped value with `UIProgressView`. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Is there any chance for increase that value.?